# Step Response Parallel RLC

Tags: passive-networks

Can anyone enlighten me on how to approach this question? I had tried solving it for hours and still doesn't have a clue. The circuit is an overdamped circuit and required to find the parameters. Please help!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you truly have no idea at all where to start, then you are trying to get into the wrong field.  Surely you know *something*.  If not, bail out now.

We can help when you get stuck on something specific, but aren't going to do your homework for you.

Hint: You can combine the voltage and the current source into a single equivalent source.  Look up *Thevenin* and *Norton* sources.  You can go further and combine that with R3.  I would simplify the whole thing to a Thevenin source driving a parallel LC, with the appropriate initial conditions.

Comment: Thank you so much for the hint. I am trying to solve it now and you are right, I think I do know something after reading your hints. Not gonna bail out and I will give my best. Thanks again!